# Application crashing on non-development system

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I've had following error on another system:

```
Faulting application name: EyeScanner.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5049fcd9
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba220dc
Exception code: 0xc0000417
Fault offset: 0x000000000007038c
Faulting process id: 0x928
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd8d2ac9ca4d5e
Faulting application path: C:\EyeScanner-Exe\EyeScanner.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
Report Id: 0fbfc252-f91e-11e1-85b1-5442495a44cf
```

The same code worked perfectly fine on my development system, and on another system which should be the same version as the failing system.

When I wanted to debug this, I tried to install WinDbg with the Windows SDK, which required me to install the .NET 4.5 Framework. After having installed it, everything worked fine even on the failing system.

Now I wonder how to find out from the above message that this was related to the .NET Framework, especially since the error code 0xC0000417 indicated that the C-Runtime (I have a DLL which does all the work for image analysis) was called with wrong parameter.

Why would it fault with that error? (.NET 4.0 was already installed beforehand, so only the update to 4.5 fixed it).

Comment: Are you mixing debug/release libraries?

Comment: No, it was all release modules. 64bit though, but everything release.

Comment: Is it was associated with machine or application config files? and it wasnt replaced properly?

Comment: Check if the faulting system has a new version of MSVCR100.dll now, after those installations.

Comment: Sorry Raj, what exactly are you asking for? I have a application config, but I double checked, it was properly set up. @MadKeithV, when I encountered that error, I double checked the version, and they were different originally. I downloaded the VS2010 SP1 Redist, and the MSVCR100.dll version was same as on the development system. Again, only the .NET update fixed it, but I dont understand why.

Comment: The exception code is too generic to diagnose anything from it.  Stack corruption is a serious problem, you do need to chase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your development machine has .Net 4.5 on it. A lot of things changed in .Net 4.5, especially with their JIT code and how aggressively they handle P/Invokes. I've ran into more than 1 problem with it so far. I've never heard of one application working in .Net 4.5 and not in 4.0, but I wouldn't say it's impossible.

Anyway, I'd try uninstalling .Net 4.5 and using the version of WinDbg for .Net 4.0 on the machine. This may help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Okay, will do so. Thanks for that information on the P/Invoke, I was not aware that they changed how it is handled.

Comment: @AntonRoth well it's not "changed". I mean it still follows the CLR spec, but it's much less conservative now. This basically means that usually it will crash more often with bugs in your P/Invoke code.